# convert window.location to window.open having a link with variable

Tags: javascript, php

Trying to implement a target=blank on this link starting from:

`window.location.href = "https://example.com/#nums=" + $("input[name=variable]").val();`

and generated this using window.open instead:

`window.open("https://example.come/#nums=" + "$("input[name=variable]"), "_blank").val();`

Any suggestions to make it work?

Comment: It's just a typo (effectively), you've copied `.val()` to the wrong place. You need to move the `.val()` so it's still attached to the `$()` result. Basically, take everything to the right of the `=` and make that the first argument to `window.open`: `window.open("https://example.com/#nums=" + $("input[name=variable]").val(), "_blank");`

Comment: Voted to close as typo/non-repro/not-useful-to-others-in-future.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @t.j Crowder, your suggestion fixed the issue

`window.open("https://example.com/#nums=" + $("input[name=variable]").val(), "_blank");`